# UIScrollView Vertical Scroll Indicator

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, vertical-scrolling

I have a problem with vertical scroll indicator its not showing after I set content size.

see this code:

```
    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    [textView setAttributedText:attributeString];
    [textView setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, self.view.frame.size.width -20, 100)];

    [textView sizeToFit];
    [textView setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, self.view.frame.size.width -20,
                                        textView.frame.size.height +15)];

    [self.scrollView addSubview:textView];
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width,
                                               textView.frame.size.height +20)];

    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 
                                                   self.scrollView.bounds.size.width,
                                                   self.scrollView.bounds.size.height)
                                                   animated:YES];

    [self.scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [self.scrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:YES];
```

any help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but I try this and it's working well

```
[self.scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES]; 
[self.scrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];     
[self.scrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what is your scrollview's height, if scrollview's height > its content size then scrollview is not able to scroll.

Comment: scrollview height = view heigh

Comment: NSLog(@"%f", self.scrollView.frame.size.height) = 628.000000 on iPhone 6 plus

Comment: NSLog(@"%f", self.scrollView.contentSize.height); = 1820.333333

Comment: UITextView it self is scrollable

Comment: [textView setScrollEnabled:NO];
        [textView setEditable:NO];